# Function that already running don't call it next time

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on `AngularJS` project I am using ng-repeat to show data, There is a `Edit` button that enable editing for particular row. On edit button click there is `Save` and `Cancel` button shows. On save button click it call `$http.post` to update data in database. Data are shown in `gal` unit and store as `liter` so when I click on save button it first convert to `liter` and then store in db.


Now the problem is when I click on `Save` button for once it work correctly, But when I click twice on Save button it convert gal -> liter -> liter and then save to db.

So I want to do is if `$http` request is already in process then do not accept another `$http` request.

I have tried to disable the button but still it is clickable.

HTML:

```
<div class="taxi_output" ng-repeat="item in vmDosings.data track by $index" >
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 text-center one" ng-bind="item.dos_nr"></div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 text-center two">
                                    <div ng-if="item.enableContent">
                                         <input id="{{$index}}" class="font-size input-{{$index}}" ng-class="{ 'error' : vmDosings.error.level || vmDosings.error.undef || vmDosings.error.exist }" type="text" ng-model="item.level" ng-change="itemChanges(item)"  ng-disabled="!item.enableContent"/> {{::$root.getEinheiten($root.GlobalData.config.volumemessurement)}}
                                    </div>
                                   <div ng-if="!item.enableContent" >
                                        <p class=""> {{ item.level  + ' ' + $root.getEinheiten($root.GlobalData.config.volumemessurement)}} </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4" ng-if="item.enableContent == false" style="vertical-align: middle">
                                   <a  class="btn" ng-click="enableContent(item, $index)" event-focus="click" event-focus-id="{{$index}}" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip="{{::$root.getLabel('edit')}}">
                                        <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="btn" ng-if="vmDosings.data.length > 1" ng-click="removeFromList(item, $index)" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip="{{::$root.getLabel('delete')}}">
                                        <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4" ng-if="item.enableContent == true">
                                    <a  class="btn"  ng-click="saveChanges(item, $index)" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip="{{::$root.getLabel('save')}}">
                                        <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa fa-save fa-2x"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="btn" ng-click="removeFromList(item, $index)" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip="{{::$root.getLabel('delete')}}">
                                        <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="btn" ng-click="restoreChanges(item)"  tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip="{{::$root.getLabel('reset')}}">
                                        <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa fa-remove fa-2x"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div ng-if="item.enableContent && vmDosings.validate == false">
                                        <div class="panel panel-danger" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:0px;">
                                            <div class="panel-heading" style="padding:0">
                                                <ul style="padding: 5px 0px 5px 30px;">
                                                    <li ng-if="vmDosings.error.level" ng-bind="getLabel('only_floats_with_one_digit')"></li>
                                                    <li ng-if="vmDosings.error.undef" ng-bind="getLabel('inputs_empty_not_allowed')"></li>
                                                    <li ng-if="vmDosings.error.exist" ng-bind="getLabel('data_already_exist')"></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                        </div>
```

AngulrJS:
Enable Edit Mode:

```
$scope.enableContent = function(data, $index) {

            angular.forEach(vmDosings.data, function(value, key) {
                vmDosings.data[key].enableContent = (value.id == data.id ? true : false );
            });
            $timeout(function () {
              $('.input-'+ $index).focus();
              $('.input-'+ $index).val($('.input-'+ $index).val());
            });
      }
```

save button click:
$rootScope.GlobalData.config.volumemessurement get the id of unit

$rootScope.calcunits(9, id, data['level']); is a function for convert

```
$scope.saveChanges = function(data) {
          var id = $rootScope.GlobalData.config.volumemessurement; 
          data['level'] = $rootScope.calcunits(id, 9, data['level']);
          checkValues(data);
          var checked = true;
          for (i in vmDosings.error) {
            if (vmDosings.error[i]) {
              checked = false;
              vmDosings.validate = false;
              break;
            }
          }
          if(checked == true) {
             DosingsServices.saveChanges(data).then(function (result) {
                if( result.data.message == 'success' && result.data.status == 200) {
                    DosingsServices.getDosings($stateParams.taxi_id).then(function (result) {
                      //vmDosings.data = result.data.dosings
                      var data = result.data.dosings;
                      var id = $rootScope.GlobalData.config.volumemessurement;
                      var i = 0;
                      for(i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
                        angular.forEach(data[i], function(value, key){
                          if(key == "level")
                             data[i][key] = $rootScope.calcunits(9, id, value)
                        });
                      }
                      vmDosings.data = data;
                  });
                }
                else if( result.data.message == 'Data Already Exist') {
                  data['level'] = $rootScope.calcunits(9, id, data['level']);
                  vmDosings.error.exist = true;
                  vmDosings.validate = false;
                }
            });
          }
        }
```

Comment: show your code. and to see what you tried

Comment: you can disable the save button if it has been clicked already.

Comment: I have added the code @Gopalakrishnan. I have try to disable nut still it is clickable Pradeepb

Answer (score 3):

What you need is **interceptors** method of **$httpProvider**. It give you full control over any http call within Angular scope ( request,requestError,response,responseError methods).

If service call is already in progress you can skip next call or put it in a queue to call once you get response from previous call any other thing you want to do

```
    // register the interceptor as a service

$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
      return {
        // optional method
        'request': function(config) {
          // do something on success
          return config;
        },

        // optional method
       'requestError': function(rejection) {
          // do something on error
          return $q.reject(rejection);
        },



        // optional method
        'response': function(response) {
          // do something on success
          return response;
        },

        // optional method
       'responseError': function(rejection) {
          // do something on error
          return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
      };
    });

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

Answer (score -1):

Set a flag `var inProgress = true;` before your post method. Check on if this flag is set before you post. Set flag to false when post method is finished (finally).

You can also use this flag to enable/disable save button.